# Can I Use BLE in android wear os?

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to know it's possible to use BLE in android wear device(with Wear OS device) with out phone(device)

I know that it's possible to use BLE in android wear with phone but I'm not sure without phone(wear alone)

I can't find that solution

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it, what do you mean? You can have apps that work along with phone app; apps that depends on the phone app; and apps that works independently from the phone app.

Comment: @DouglasSilva I mean the wear os app is independently from the phone app, then can I use BLE ? I want to know it's possible to use ble independently from the phone app only watch
and watch is Wear OS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @박성범 Yes you can use Android wear without phone to connect with BLE device.